# How to combine a input and a hidden value in a form?

Tags: php, jquery

I would like to know if there is a way to add a (hidden) value to a input value in a form.

For example, I would like to have a number input like so :

`<input type="number" name='questionA' hidden_added_to_the_input_value="+test">`
(the code doesn't work), the user enters '32', and the final value $_POST['questionA] = '32+test'

I think i will have to use js to do that, any help appreciate thanks :)

Comment: Why do you need `+test` on the end?  As a user can manipulate any input from the front end, it would be easy for them to submit anything they wanted, so if it has to have this extra text it may be better to add it on the backend.

Comment: Yes true, this is a good question. I had to mark the input with something like '-test' because i wanted it after to calculate a score with all the input contening '-test' and i didn't know which input has to be taking in count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean this?

```js
const hiddenValue = 4; // or from a hidden field
document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit", function() {
  const qa = document.getElementById("questionA");
  qa.value = +qa.value + hiddenValue; // convert to number and add
  console.log(qa.value);
})
```

```html
<form id="form1" action="somephp.php" method="POST">
  <input type="number" name='questionA' id="questionA">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this "normally". But we have two options:

1. Use HTML

```js
<input type="hidden" name='hidden_questionA' value="-32">
<input type="number" name='questionA'>
```

As a result you will have 2 values in PHP:

```php
$questionA = 0 + $_POST['questionA'] + $_POST['hidden_questionA']; // If you use integers
```

2. Use JavaScript

For example, we can use code from @mplungjan:

```js
document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit",function() {
  const qa = document.getElementById("questionA");
  const hiddenValueQA = qa.getAttribute("my-hidden-value");
  qa.value = +qa.value + +hiddenValueQA; // convert to integers
  console.log(qa.value); // <-- this is just for testing
})
```

```html
<form id="form1" action="somephp.php" method="POST">
<input type="number" name='questionA' id="questionA" my-hidden-value="-32">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

P.S. I've used `-32` as example to show that you can use positive and negative values for your hidden field.

Comment: @mplungjan =) yeah, why not